# Solr Case-insensitive Query

Tags: java, spring, solr, solrj

I need to filter a query (fq) in a case-insensitive way.
All the solutions I see online has to do with editing the file schema.xml.

However, I don't have this file since I'm using a schema less Solr (data-driven config set).

How can I still achieve this result?
Many thanks!

Comment: does that mean you are using managed-schema.xml?

Comment: No. 
Non of my cores have this file and I can only see this file in the config-sets directory (the default)

Comment: what field are you searching against..?do you the know the fieldType of that field?

Comment: I have a field called "name_s" which contains a string.
I would like to query againt this field but case - insensitive.

Comment: _ss uses the fieldType String so its not possible in your case...

Comment: you can try to have the field name as name_t...or name_txt...and then try

Comment: because here you are using the dynamic fields and its field name is *_ss and type is String...

Comment: I fixed it to "name_s". is it still impossible to query?

Comment: please check my answer below...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109158/discussion-between-abhijit-bashetti-and-yuz).

Comment: Where Do you define fields?

Comment: @yuz: Is it resolved for you?

Comment: @Oyeme: As the op is using the dynamicFields, he need not have define fields..its the dynamicFields which makes solr as schemaless..Solr’s dynamic field capability reduces up-front configuration requirements for fields with predictable naming patterns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using the `dynamicField` defined in the `managed-schema file`.
You are using the pattern

as your field also ends with `*_ss` pattern as `name_ss`.
Here as you see the field `*_ss` has the type strings and these are not analysed or rather indexed as it is.

I suggest you to use below `dynamicField`

```
<dynamicField name="*_txt" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Here the `text_general` type is built like below in the `managed-schema` file

```
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory"
         pattern="-" replacement=""/>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory"
         pattern="." replacement=""/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

So you will have the field as `name_txt`.